# OpenGL texture distortion on 3D model

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, texture-mapping

I'm building a 3D model viewer in OpenGL 3.3 but I can't get my textures to show properly. I'm pretty sure the texcoords (coming from the object I'm loading) are correct.

This is my code: 
main.cpp

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>

    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

    #include "glm/glm.hpp"
    #include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
    #include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"

    #include "InputState.h"
    #include "Viewer.h"
    #include "Shader.hpp"

    #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
    #include "stb_image.h"

    #define TINYOBJLOADER_IMPLEMENTATION
    #include "tiny_obj_loader.h"

    std::string folder = "cube-tex/";
    std::string objPath = folder + "cube-tex.obj";
    std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes;
    std::vector<tinyobj::material_t> materials;
    std::vector<GLuint> texID;


    std::string meshMode = "WIREFRAME";
    std::string lightMode = "DIRECTIONAL";

    double startTime = glfwGetTime();

    float initScale = 1;
    float zoom = 0;
    float xRot, yRot;

    int winX = 500;
    int winY = 500;

    std::vector<unsigned int> vaoHandle;

    ObjectViewer *ObjCam;
    Viewer *Camera;

    glm::vec3 cameraPos(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);

    // Data structure storing mouse input info
    InputState Input;

    unsigned int programID;
    unsigned int debugShader;
    unsigned int lightTexShader;

    //
    // Callbacks
    //
    void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window,
                      int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        if (action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            switch(key)
                {
                case GLFW_KEY_S:
                  if (programID == lightTexShader) {
                    programID = debugShader;
                    meshMode = "WIREFRAME";
                    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
                  }
                  else {
                    programID = lightTexShader;
                    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
                  }
                  break;
                case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE: // escape key pressed
                  glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
                  break;
                case GLFW_KEY_D:
                  if(programID == debugShader){
                    if(meshMode == "WIREFRAME") {
                      glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
                      meshMode = "NORMAL";
                    }else if(meshMode == "NORMAL"){
                      meshMode = "MATERIAL";
                    }else{
                      glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
                      meshMode = "WIREFRAME";
                    }
                  }
                  break;
                case GLFW_KEY_L:
                  if(programID == lightTexShader){
                    if(lightMode == "DIRECTIONAL") {
                      lightMode = "HEADLIGHT";
                    }else if(lightMode == "HEADLIGHT"){
                      lightMode = "ROTATING";
                    }else{
                      lightMode = "DIRECTIONAL";
                    }
                  }
                  break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
        }

    }

    // Set the projection matrix. Takes into account window aspect ratio, so called
    // when the window is resized.
    void setProjection(unsigned int id)
    {
        glm::mat4 projection;

        projection = glm::perspective( (float)M_PI/3.0f, (float) winX / winY, 1.0f, 30.0f );

        // Load it to the shader program
        int projHandle = glGetUniformLocation(id, "projection");
        if (projHandle == -1) {
            std::cout << "Uniform: projection_matrix is not an active uniform label\n";
        }
        glUniformMatrix4fv( projHandle, 1, false, glm::value_ptr(projection) );
    }

    // Called when the window is resized.
    void reshape_callback( GLFWwindow *window, int x, int y )
    {
        winX = x;
        winY = y;
        setProjection(programID);
        glViewport( 0, 0, x, y );
    }

    void mouse_pos_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y)
    {
        // Use a global data structure to store mouse info
        // We can then use it however we want
        Input.update((float)x, (float)y);
    }

    void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
    {
        if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            Input.rMousePressed = true;
        }
        else if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
            Input.rMousePressed = false;
        }
        else if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            Input.lMousePressed = true;
        }
        else if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
            Input.lMousePressed = false;
        }
    }

    int setupLight()
    {
      // light position uniform
      int lightposHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "light_pos");
      if (lightposHandle == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't find matrix uniforms\n");
        exit(1);
      }
      // Uniform lighting variables
      int lightambientHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "light_ambient");
        int lightdiffuseHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "light_diffuse");
        int lightspecularHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "light_specular");
        if ( lightambientHandle == -1 ||
        lightdiffuseHandle == -1 ||
        lightspecularHandle == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't find light uniform variables\n");
            return 1;
      }

      float lightPos[4];   // light position //= { 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

      float lightambient[3];    // ambient light components
      float lightdiffuse[3];    // diffuse light components
      float lightspecular[3];   // specular light components

      if(lightMode == "DIRECTIONAL"){
        lightambient[0] = 0.0f;
        lightambient[1] = 0.0f;
        lightambient[2] = 0.0f;
        lightdiffuse[0] = 0.5f;
        lightdiffuse[1] = 0.5f;
        lightdiffuse[2] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[0] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[1] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[2] = 1.0f;

        lightPos[0] = -10.0f;
        lightPos[1] = -10.0f;
        lightPos[2] = -10.0f;
        lightPos[3] = 0.0f;

      }else if(lightMode == "HEADLIGHT"){
        lightambient[0] = 0.0f;
        lightambient[1] = 0.0f;
        lightambient[2] = 0.0f;
        lightdiffuse[0] = 1.0f;
        lightdiffuse[1] = 1.0f;
        lightdiffuse[2] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[0] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[1] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[2] = 1.0f;

        glm::mat3 rotMat(Camera->getViewMtx());
        glm::vec3 d((Camera->getViewMtx())[3]);
        glm::vec3 tmp = -d * rotMat;
        lightPos[0] = tmp[0];
        lightPos[1] = tmp[1];
        lightPos[2] = tmp[2];
        lightPos[3] = 1.0f;

      }else if(lightMode == "ROTATING"){
        lightambient[0] = 0.0f;
        lightambient[1] = 0.0f;
        lightambient[2] = 0.0f;
        lightdiffuse[0] = 1.0f;
        lightdiffuse[1] = 1.0f;
        lightdiffuse[2] = 0.2f;
        lightspecular[0] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[1] = 1.0f;
        lightspecular[2] = 0.2f;

        double now = glfwGetTime();
        lightPos[0] = 10 * cos((now - startTime));
        lightPos[1] = 0.0f;
        lightPos[2] = 10 * sin((now - startTime));
        lightPos[3] = 1.0f;
      }

      glUniform4fv(lightposHandle, 1, lightPos);

        glUniform3fv(lightambientHandle, 1, lightambient);
        glUniform3fv(lightdiffuseHandle, 1, lightdiffuse);
        glUniform3fv(lightspecularHandle, 1, lightspecular);

        return 0;   // return success
    }

    void computeInitScale(){
      float minX = 0;
      float minY = 0;
      float maxX = 0;
      float maxY = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < shapes[i].mesh.positions.size()/3; j++){
          //max and min X
          if(shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+0] > maxX){
            maxX = shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+0];
          }else if(shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+0] < minX){
            minX = shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+0];
          }
          //max and min Y
          if(shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+1] > maxY){
            maxY = shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+1];
          }else if(shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+1] < minY){
            minY = shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*j+1];
          }
        }
      }

      initScale = 2 / std::max(maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
    }

    void loadRGBTexture(const char *path)
    {
        int x, y, n;

        // Load from file. Force RGB image pixel format
        unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &x, &y, &n, 3);

        // Copy to GPU as data for the currently active texture.
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, x, y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

        stbi_image_free(data);

        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    void setMaterials(int i){
      // material
      int mtlambientHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "mtl_ambient");
      int mtldiffuseHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "mtl_diffuse");
      int mtlspecularHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "mtl_specular");

      if (mtlambientHandle == -1 || mtldiffuseHandle == -1 || mtlspecularHandle == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: can't find material uniform variables\n");
      }

      float mtlambient[3];
      mtlambient[0] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].ambient[0];
      mtlambient[1] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].ambient[1];
      mtlambient[2] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].ambient[2];
      float mtldiffuse[3];
      mtldiffuse[0] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].diffuse[0];
      mtldiffuse[1] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].diffuse[1];
      mtldiffuse[2] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].diffuse[2];
      float mtlspecular[3];
      mtlspecular[0] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].specular[0];
      mtlspecular[1] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].specular[1];
      mtlspecular[2] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].specular[2];


      glUniform3fv(mtlambientHandle, 1, mtlambient);
      glUniform3fv(mtldiffuseHandle, 1, mtldiffuse);
      glUniform3fv(mtlspecularHandle, 1, mtlspecular);

    }

    void loadObj(){

      std::string err;
      bool ret = tinyobj::LoadObj(shapes, materials, err, objPath.c_str(), folder.c_str());

      if (!err.empty()) {
        std::cerr << err << std::endl;
      }

      if (!ret) {
        exit(1);
      }

      std::cout << "# of shapes    : " << shapes.size() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "# of materials : " << materials.size() << std::endl;

      for (size_t i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
        printf("shape[%ld].name = %s\n", i, shapes[i].name.c_str());
        printf("Size of shape[%ld].indices: %ld\n", i, shapes[i].mesh.indices.size());
        printf("Size of shape[%ld].material_ids: %ld\n", i, shapes[i].mesh.material_ids.size());
        assert((shapes[i].mesh.indices.size() % 3) == 0);
        for (size_t f = 0; f < shapes[i].mesh.indices.size() / 3; f++) {
          printf("  idx[%ld] = %d, %d, %d. mat_id = %d\n", f, shapes[i].mesh.indices[3*f+0], shapes[i].mesh.indices[3*f+1], shapes[i].mesh.indices[3*f+2], shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[f]);
        }

        printf("shape[%ld].vertices: %ld\n", i, shapes[i].mesh.positions.size());
        assert((shapes[i].mesh.positions.size() % 3) == 0);
        for (size_t v = 0; v < shapes[i].mesh.positions.size() / 3; v++) {
          printf("  v[%ld] = (%f, %f, %f)\n", v,
            shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*v+0],
            shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*v+1],
            shapes[i].mesh.positions[3*v+2]);
        }
      }

      for (size_t i = 0; i < materials.size(); i++) {
        printf("material[%ld].name = %s\n", i, materials[i].name.c_str());
        printf("  material.Ka = (%f, %f ,%f)\n", materials[i].ambient[0], materials[i].ambient[1], materials[i].ambient[2]);
        printf("  material.Kd = (%f, %f ,%f)\n", materials[i].diffuse[0], materials[i].diffuse[1], materials[i].diffuse[2]);
        printf("  material.Ks = (%f, %f ,%f)\n", materials[i].specular[0], materials[i].specular[1], materials[i].specular[2]);
        printf("  material.Tr = (%f, %f ,%f)\n", materials[i].transmittance[0], materials[i].transmittance[1], materials[i].transmittance[2]);
        printf("  material.Ke = (%f, %f ,%f)\n", materials[i].emission[0], materials[i].emission[1], materials[i].emission[2]);
        printf("  material.Ns = %f\n", materials[i].shininess);
        printf("  material.Ni = %f\n", materials[i].ior);
        printf("  material.dissolve = %f\n", materials[i].dissolve);
        printf("  material.illum = %d\n", materials[i].illum);
        printf("  material.map_Ka = %s\n", materials[i].ambient_texname.c_str());
        printf("  material.map_Kd = %s\n", materials[i].diffuse_texname.c_str());
        printf("  material.map_Ks = %s\n", materials[i].specular_texname.c_str());
        printf("  material.map_Ns = %s\n", materials[i].specular_highlight_texname.c_str());
        std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it(materials[i].unknown_parameter.begin());
        std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator itEnd(materials[i].unknown_parameter.end());
        for (; it != itEnd; it++) {
          printf("  material.%s = %s\n", it->first.c_str(), it->second.c_str());
        }
        printf("\n");
      }

      computeInitScale();
    }

    void createVAO()
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++){
        vaoHandle.push_back(0);
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle[i]);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle[i]);

        unsigned int buffer[5];
        glGenBuffers(4, buffer);

        // Set vertex attribute
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                       sizeof(float) * shapes[i].mesh.positions.size(), &shapes[i].mesh.positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        // Set vertex attribute
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[1]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                       sizeof(float) * shapes[i].mesh.normals.size(), &shapes[i].mesh.normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        // create material array
        float diffuse[shapes[i].mesh.indices.size() * 3];

        for(int j = 0; j<shapes[i].mesh.indices.size(); j++){
          int index = j*3;
          diffuse[index] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[j/3]].diffuse[0];
          diffuse[index + 1] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[j/3]].diffuse[1];
          diffuse[index + 2] = materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[j/3]].diffuse[2];
        }

        // Set vertex attribute
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[2]);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                       shapes[i].mesh.indices.size() * 3 * sizeof(float) , &diffuse[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);



        // Set element attributes. Notice the change to using GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[3]);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                       sizeof(float) * shapes[i].mesh.indices.size(), &shapes[i].mesh.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // load textures
        texID.push_back(0);
        glGenTextures(1, &texID[i] );
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID[i] );
        loadRGBTexture((folder + (std::string) materials[shapes[i].mesh.material_ids[0]].diffuse_texname).c_str());

        // load texture coordinates
        int texLoc = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "a_tex_coord");

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[4]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                      shapes[i].mesh.texcoords.size() * sizeof(float) , &shapes[i].mesh.texcoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texLoc);
        glVertexAttribPointer(texLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);


        // Un-bind
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);



      }
    }

    void render()
    {
      glUseProgram(programID);
      glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

      setProjection(programID);

      Camera->update(Input);

      glm::mat4 viewMatrix;
      viewMatrix = Camera->getViewMtx();

        // Load viex to the shader program
        int viewHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "view");
        if (viewHandle == -1) {
            std::cout << "Uniform: view is not an active uniform label\n";
        }
        glUniformMatrix4fv( viewHandle, 1, false, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix) );

      // Load the model matrix
      int modelUniformHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "model");
      if (modelUniformHandle == -1)
        exit(1);

      // calculate zoom
      if(Input.rMousePressed){
        zoom += Input.yDiff/10;
        if (zoom < 0) zoom = 0;
        if (zoom > 1.5) zoom = 1.5;
      }

      glm::mat4 model;
      model = glm::scale( model, glm::vec3(initScale + zoom, initScale + zoom, initScale + zoom));
      glUniformMatrix4fv( modelUniformHandle, 1, false, glm::value_ptr(model) );

      if (programID == debugShader){
        // set colour mode
        int modeHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "mode");
        if (modeHandle == -1) {
          std::cout << "Uniform: mode is not an active uniform label\n";
        }

        if(meshMode == "MATERIAL"){
          glUniform1i( modeHandle, 1);
        }else{
          glUniform1i( modeHandle, 0);
        }

      }else{
        setupLight();
      }

      // Load meshes
      for(int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++){
        glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle[i]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, shapes[i].mesh.indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        if (programID == lightTexShader){
          setMaterials(i);
          int texHandle = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "texMap");
          if (texHandle == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not find uniform variables\n");
            exit(1);
          }
          glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID[i]);
          glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
          glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

        }
        glBindVertexArray(0);
      }
    }




    /**
     * Error callback for GLFW. Simply prints error message to stderr.
     */
    static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
    {
        fputs(description, stderr);
    }

    int main (int argc, char **argv)
    {
      GLFWwindow* window;
      glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

      if (!glfwInit()) {
          exit(1);
      }

      // Specify that we want OpenGL 3.3
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

      // Create the window and OpenGL context
      window = glfwCreateWindow(winX, winY, "Modelling and viewing", NULL, NULL);
      if (!window)
      {
          glfwTerminate();
          exit(1);
      }

      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
      glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Initialize GLEW
        glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
            exit(1);
        }

      // load shaders
      debugShader = LoadShaders("mview.vert", "mview.frag");
      lightTexShader = LoadShaders("light-texture.vert", "light-texture.frag");

      if (debugShader == 0 || lightTexShader == 0) {
        exit(1);
      }
      programID = debugShader;

      // Set OpenGL state we need for this application.
      glClearColor(0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F, 0.0F);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glUseProgram(programID);
      glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

      // Set up the scene and the cameras
      //setProjection(debugShader);
      //setProjection(lightTexShader);


      loadObj();
      createVAO();

      ObjCam = new ObjectViewer( cameraPos );
      Camera = ObjCam;

      // Define callback functions and start main loop
      glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
      glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_pos_callback);
      glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_button_callback);
      glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, reshape_callback);

      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
      {
          render();

          glfwSwapBuffers(window);
          glfwPollEvents();
      }

      glfwDestroyWindow(window);
      glfwTerminate();
      exit(0);

      return 0;
    }
```

Vertex shader

```
 #version 330

 uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
 uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;
 //uniform mat3 normal_matrix;

 layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_vertex;
 layout (location = 1) in vec3 a_normal;
 layout (location = 2) in vec3 a_diffuse;
 in vec2 a_tex_coord;

 uniform mat4 projection;
 uniform mat4 view;
 uniform mat4 model;
 //uniform int mode;
 uniform vec3 mtl_diffuse;

 out vec4 vertex; // vertex position in eye space
 out vec3 normal; // the eye space normal
 out vec2 st;

 void main(void)
 {
   vertex = view * model * vec4(a_vertex, 1.0);
   //normal = normalize(normal_matrix * a_normal);
   normal = a_normal;
   st = a_tex_coord;
   gl_Position =  projection * view * model * vec4(a_vertex, 1.0);
 }
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 330

in vec4 vertex;
in vec3 normal;
in vec2 st;

out vec4 fragColour;

uniform sampler2D texMap;

uniform vec4 light_pos;

uniform vec3 light_ambient;     // Light ambient RGBA values
uniform vec3 light_diffuse;     // Light diffuse RGBA values
uniform vec3 light_specular;    // Light specular RGBA values

uniform vec3 mtl_ambient;  // Ambient surface colour
uniform vec3 mtl_diffuse;  // Diffuse surface colour
uniform vec3 mtl_specular; // Specular surface colour

const float shininess = 32;


vec3 phongPointLight(in vec4 position, in vec3 norm)
{
    vec3 s = normalize(vec3(light_pos - position));
    if(light_pos.w == 0.0){
      s = -normalize(light_pos.xyz);
    }

    vec3 v = normalize(-position.xyz);
    vec3 r = reflect( -s, norm );

    vec3 ambient = light_ambient * mtl_ambient;

    // The diffuse component
    float sDotN = max( dot(s,norm), 0.0 );
    vec3 diffuse = light_diffuse * mtl_diffuse * sDotN;

    // The specular component BLINN
    vec3 spec = vec3(0.0);
    vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(s + v);

    if ( sDotN > 0.0 )
    spec = light_specular * mtl_specular * pow(max(dot(normalize(normal), halfwayDir), 0.0), 32.0);

    return ambient + diffuse + spec;
}

void main(void)
{
    fragColour = vec4(phongPointLight(vertex, normalize(normal)), 1.0) * texture(texMap, st);
}
```

[image]

This is the result. As you can see the texture is not properly positioned on the car.

Comment: try to debug it with minimal model, e.g. a cube

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do but no luck so far

Comment: Why do you specify the `location` for everything but `a_tex_coord` attribute?

Comment: I tried to specify the location and the objects disappeared, so I tried this other way and it worked better. Could it be the problem?

Comment: A common problem when exchanging models or code between OpenGL and DirectX is the mapping of the coordinate systems. An easy way to check if this is the problem is to invert the v-component of the texture coordinates when you sample.

Comment: @RobiNoob Define a plane (Rectangle consisting of two triangles), as your mesh in an obj file, with appropriate uv coordinates. This is a very simple mesh and you should be able to "hand write" all the values. Then load that model with a simple texture. It will give you an idea as to whatis wrong.